# Adding a new Column to DF in Loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a loop and I am trying to create a new column to a list of lists with a constant number that is dependent on the value j (j is a number from 1 to 12). The rest of the loop works and the previous line renames the columns of the same dataframe.

```
for(i in 1:length(idw.list)){
  idw.output[[i]] <- list()
  for(j in 1:length(idw.list[[i]])){
    idw.output[[i]][[j]]= as.data.frame(idw.list[[i]][[j]]) 
    names(idw.output[[i]][[j]])[1:3] <- c("LON", "LAT", "MAXMEAN")
    (idw.output[[i]][[j]])[, "MONTH"] = j
}
}
```

I have tried this:

```
(idw.output[[i]][[j]])[, "MONTH"] = j
```

which leads to this error:

```
Error in (idw.output[[i]][[j]]) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  could not find function "(<-"
```

Right now the data looks like this:

```
    LON          LAT        MAXMEAN
1   11.66847    -18.04208   30.07742    
2   11.76847    -18.04208   30.07742    
3   11.86847    -18.04208   30.07742
```

and i would like to add the column, so that in the case j=1 (first loop):

```
    LON          LAT        MAXMEAN    MONTH
1   11.66847    -18.04208   30.07742    1
2   11.76847    -18.04208   30.07742    1
3   11.86847    -18.04208   30.07742    1
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Probably there is a better way to do this. It would be helpful if you could share a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: Convert `(idw.output[[i]][[j]])[, "MONTH"] = j` to `idw.output[[i]][[j]][, "MONTH"] = j`. (Parenthesis are gone). Also this is quite horrible practice. I suggest creating a small example for example 2 idenical `data.frames` with 3 observations, with the expected result. Likely this will yield an answer with better code.

Comment: Thanks! It worked and I will change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post isn't really reproducible and this is too long for a comment but maybe you can try

```
for(i in seq_along(idw.list)) {
   for(j in seq_along(idw.list[[i]])) {
       names(idw.list[[i]][[j]])[1:3] <- c("LON", "LAT", "MAXMEAN")
       idw.list[[i]][[j]]["Month"] = j
     }
}
```